# xml help using xpath string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

found the following code:

```
XmlDocument cfgDoc = new XmlDocument();
        loadConfigDoc(cfgDoc);
        // retrieve the appSettings node 
        node = cfgDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ETicketMailboxSettings");

        if (node == null)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("appSettings section not found");
        }

        try
        {
            // XPath select setting "add" element that contains this key    
            XmlElement addElem = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='" + key + "']");
            if (addElem != null)
            {
                addElem.SetAttribute("value", value);
            }
            // not found, so we need to add the element, key and value
            else
            {
                XmlElement entry = cfgDoc.CreateElement("add");
                entry.SetAttribute("key", key);
                entry.SetAttribute("value", value);
                node.AppendChild(entry);
            }
            //save it
            saveConfigDoc(cfgDoc, docName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

what do the double slashes tell the compiler?

```
.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='"
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_1.0#Axis_specifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look anywhere in the XML document. This is an XML query language.

A single slash would look from the root of an XML document.

Comment: thanks, does single slash mean anything, is this a c# or xml thing where i can look it up

Comment: This is an XML query language called xpath...have a look at the provided links.

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades & @BoltClock +1 for the links.

Answer (score 2):

Selects all nodes (in this case nodes named `add` with a specific attribute `key`) in the entire document.

A single slash means 'matching from the root of the document'.